# I want to set an animated image in my application

Tags: android-animation

I want to set an animated image in my application.i use an animation-list to show it frame by frame but it's  not working!!
please help me!!

here is Java code

```
_imagView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
_imagView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
AnimationDrawable anim1 = (AnimationDrawable) _imagView.getBackground();    
anim1.start();
```

and here is anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking0" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking1" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking2" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking3" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking4" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking5" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking6" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking7" android:duration="500" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/animationchoking8" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Development guide,you should not call start method directly in onCreate() of your Activity([Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) at the bottom).Try this:

```
   _imagView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            anim1.start();
        }
    });
```